# How to store the following structure in a relational database?

Tags: sql, database, relational

I have the following data types that I want to store in a relational database:

```
Phase {
  product: Product;
  name: string;
  phases: Phase[]; - I want this to be as subset of phases from the **product.phases**
}

Product {
  name: string;
  phases: Phase[];
}
```

Can this be done with a relational database?

To clarify the question: 
  I have a list of products. Each product has a list of phases. Each phase in the list also has a list of phases.
I want a restriction to the `product->phases->phases` to contain phases only from the `product->phases`.

Example:

```
Phases - [{ 
  name: 'phase1', 
  product: 'product1' phases: 'I want this to be a subset of ['phase1', 'phase2', 'phase3'] (the phases the 'product1' has)' }]

Products - [{ 
  name: 'product1', 
  phases: ['phase1', 'phase2', 'phase3'] 
}]
```

Can I make such restriction in a relational database?

Answer (score 1):

this is many-to-many relation, you can use third table for this :

```
#Phase:
 - id (PK)
 - name

#Product:
 - id (PK)
 - name

#ProductPhase:
 - phaseId (FK)
 - productId (FK)
```

If your code is in C#:

```
Phase {
  id: int;
  name: string;
  productsPhases: ProductPhase[];
}

Product {
  id: int;
  name: string;
  productsPhases: ProductPhase[];
}

ProductPhase {
  PhaseId: int;
  Phase: Phase;
  ProductId: int;
  Product: Product
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming from your question that a product has phases but not the other way around which is a "One to Many" relation but the following structure can also represent "Many to Many" relations which go in both directions:

```
create table phase(
  phase_id int primary key,
  phase_name varchar(20)
);

create table product(
  product_id int primary key,
  product_name varchar(20)
);

create table product_phases(
  phase_id int,
  product_id int,
  primary key (phase_id,product_id),
  foreign key (phase_id) references phase(phase_id),
  foreign key (product_id) references product(product_id) 
);
```

Comment: I want each phase to contain a list of specific phases (those present in the product). In your solution each product has a list of phases but does each phase also has a list of phases?

Answer (score 0):

Because, you want phase to refer to itself as well as other table, you will need to have a table that references to itself and a reference to other table. So, your tables design would be something like this:

```
Table Product:
Id        --Primary key for this table.
Name      -- Name of the Product.

Table Phase:
Id        --Primary key for this table.
Name      -- Phase Name
ProductId -- Foreign Key Reference To Product Table.
ParentId  -- Self reference to this Phase Table.
```

Comment: I need a restriction to the ParentID. In your example a phase can contain a phase that are not present in the Products phase list.

Comment: @DanielGrieb, I did not get you entirely. Are you saying a Phase can have multiple products and a product can have multiple phases? If this is the case, then you need many to many and yes, then you need junction table. But the example in your post does not say this. Your example just sounded like 1 product to many phases.

Answer (score 0):

```
    create table phase(
      id number pk,
      name varchar(100),
      parent_product_id number,
    );

    create table product(
      id number pk,
      name varchar(100)
    );

    create table product_phases(
      product_id number,  
      phase_id number,

      fk (phase_id) references phase(id),
      fk (product_id) references product(id) 
    );


    To get all phases of a product -
    select * from product_phases pp
    where pp.product_id=? and pp.phase_id in (select id from phase where id =? or parent_id=?)
```